# UIWebView or WKWebkit for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I am wanting to load a requested webpage and accessing elements of the DOM to return a value from one of the nodes. I have some JavaScript that does this. Question is which is best method to return the value to my app. 
 I see UIWebView has a function

stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

and WKWebKit has function

func evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString: String!, completionHandler: ((AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void)!)

Well what's the main difference between them and which is better and why for my use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, WKWebView is different to UIWebView in a few ways

- It uses the same Javascript engine that Safari uses, so it's considerably faster at Javascript evaluation (it uses just in time compilation to compile your script to machine code before running it)
- It's only supported on iOS8 and above, so won't work on older platforms
- It runs in a separate process, so crashes in the WKWebView code won't bring down your entire app.

To answer your specific question, UIWebView `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` blocks your app whilst waiting for your code to run, and so is synchronous. By contrast, because WKWebView code is running in another process, you must interact with it asynchronously; you submit your request to run Javascript to the WebKit process, and your completion handler is run when JavaScript evaluation is complete and the results ready. In the meanwhile, the thread that called `evaluateJavaScript` will continue to execute other code.

Comment: Superb explanation. Is this in the apple docs or your own personal knowledge?

Comment: The docs obviously note that [WKWebView evaluateJavaScript] is asynchronous, but I can't find any authoritative mention of the three points I made above right now. They're definitely true though. You can actually see the WebKit processes themselves in instruments, for example

Comment: I can't even find where it says its asynchronous. I guess thats why we come to SO :)